# MariaDB SSL connection error: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0

Tags: ssl, jdbc, mariadb

My environment:

```
OS: centos 7.6.1810
database: 10.3.14-MariaDB
jdbc driver: mariadb-java-client 2.4.1
jdbc parameter: jdbc:mysql://db_ip:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8mb4&useSSL=true&trustServerCertificate=true
java: openjdk version "1.8.0_201"
ap server: wildfly 16
```

MariaDB SSL configuration tested below:

```
mysql mysql --ssl

MariaDB [mysql]> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.14-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:          68
Current database:       mysql
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Current pager:          less
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.3.14-MariaDB MariaDB Server
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:            /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 24 min 1 sec
```

When I tried to establish ssl connection to mariadb using jdbc, I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.checkRecordVersion(InputRecord.java:552)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:565)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:529)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.handleConnectionPhases(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:437)
        ... 87 more
```

The jdbc driver should be the latest version, It worked before I upgrade mariadb to 10.3.14, I already tried several jdbc driver version but none worked. What should I try to solve this problem.

Comment: can you share results of "show variables like '%SSL%'" to show what SSL library is used?

Comment: sure, version_ssl_library | OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017

Comment: OpenSSL doesn't seem to recognize the TLS version in hello packet. That is set by default enabled protocol.  Could you set option "enabledSslProtocolSuites" to various values likes "TLSv1, TLSv1.1" ?

Comment: I tried 'useSSL=true&trustServerCertificate=true&enabledSslProtocolSuites=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2' in jdbc options, still no luck, Is there any setting I should in mariadb?

Comment: it's strange, change HikariCP version to 2.7.9 and mariadb-java-client to 2.2.6 fixed this problem. Might be useful for anyone who got this issue too.