# mariadb ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unsupported protocol

Tags: mysql, ssl, openssl, mariadb

I got a mairadb 10.1 on ubuntu 18.04 where I wannt to connect via SSL. In november it worked, but my selfmade certificates runed out. So I created some new ones, but since then I got this errormessage when I try to connect (in python-mariadb the code looks similary, so I guess its a mariadb problem.)

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unsupported protocol
```

When I connect via localhost from the server to the server, it works with an ssl connection.

I tried then to use another server, this time its a debian buster with mariadb 10.3 and it behaves the same.

---

Sites I already visited but haven't brought me further:

- https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/817
- [MariaDB SSL connection error: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643702/mariadb-ssl-connection-error-unsupported-record-version-unknown-0-0)
- https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#openssl-defaults

---

sudo openssl x509 -text -noout -in boba-server-cert.pem

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = ..., ST = ..., L = ..., O = ..., CN = CA B
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 21 10:48:33 2020 GMT
            Not After : Dec 21 10:48:33 2021 GMT
        Subject: C = .., ST = ..., L = ..., O = ..., CN = [domain]
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
...
```

Comment: Why not use Let's Encrypt? Important question: What protocol is supported? The client and server must have at least one in common.

Comment: It's not recommended to use letsencrypt for maraiadb. The client needs a key, cert, and ca-cert too.

Comment: Why not? If you need a signed key it's the easy way to do it. If self-signed is fine, then you can do whatever, but be sure to use a key that both client and server accept. This should not be an issue if you're using the same version of MariaDB as both client and server.

Comment: "unsupported protocol" sounds more like a problem with deprecated SSL/TLS versions than with certificates ...

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe How do you know tha SSL/TLS version?

Comment: @tadman Okay, I can't find the site anymore that recommended me not to use Letsencrypt. And I can see, that you have much experience into mysql. So do you have a Guide, how to setup mariadb and letsencrypt? which certs do i need on my client? how to give the user mysql access to the keys?

Comment: "How do you know tha SSL/TLS version?" ... because it is the same kind of error message that I got after upgrading from CentOS 7 to 8. CentOS 8 only still supports TLS v1.2 and up by default, and clients that only support TLS v1.1 or earlier get exactly that error message back